# Email Service to send and receive email in google compute engine

Tags: email, google-compute-engine, mail-server

I'm new to google compute engine, i used dedicated server before where i get cpanel to configure email so i can send and receive but in google cloud it's not available. so how can i use email service in GCE please help

Answer (score 3):

See the [docs on sending email from GCE](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/tutorials/sending-mail):

> Google Compute Engine does not allow outbound connections on ports 25, 465, and 587 but you can still set up your instances to send mail through ports 587 and 465 using servers provided through partner services, such as [SendGrid](http://sendgrid.com/). This document discusses how to set up your instances to send email using SendGrid.
>
> If you wish to send mail through a corporate mail server, you can use a VPN to bypass these restrictions. This would require running a VPN client on your Compute Engine node, and a VPN server on your corporate network router. This would allow your Compute Engine node to appear "inside" your corporate firewall, and allow unrestricted access to your corporate mail server. There are security implications for this configuration, and you should ensure that your Compute Engine node only has access to the services it requires, and nothing more.
>
> SendGrid is a partner service that provides Google Compute Engine customers with a free or paid SendGrid account that you can use to send mail from Google Compute Engine instances. SendGrid offers a number of advantages:
>
> - [free tier](http://sendgrid.com/partner/google?mbsy=gHNj)* to Google Compute Engine customers that includes 25,000 transactional email messages per month
> - Ability to send emails from addresses other than @gmail.com
> - No daily limit on the number of transactional email messages

The footnote on *free** is:

> Google will be compensated for customers who sign up for a non-free account.

See the document for details on how to sign up or set this up on your account.

Comment: Incoming connections to GCE VMs on port 25 should work just fine. It's only the [outgoing connections on port 25 that are blocked](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/networking#blockedtraffic).

Comment: so how to configure incoming emails

Comment: That's independent of GCE and that's standard mail server/SMTP documentation, which would be included in your mail server docs.

Answer (score 0):

Use email provider's API to send mail from Google Compute Engine. For that you need the end point url, and authentication key. This is easiest way as ports such as 25, 465 and 587 are blocked in Google Cloud.

Answer (score -1):

You may use your email providers API to send email from GC to avoid

Comment: If not knowing the API concepts, you can do a negative rating to the answer. If all ports such as 25, 465 and 587 are blocked, you can only use API calls to send mail. Please read and rethink of this -1.